# Setting up Qt Location to query from a local osm server

Tags: qt, geolocation, qml

I've managed to setup a local OSM server and would like to use it as my application's tile provider. However, I am facing some difficult to make the Qt Location application to connect to the local server. The following code is a simple QML application that configures the "osm.mapping.host" plugin's property with the local server address. I noticed that the Plugin ignores the configuration and retrieves the tiles from MapQuest.

I would like to know if have anyone accomplished to connect the OSM plugin to connect on a different server than the default one ?

```
    Window {
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"

        PluginParameter { name: "osm.useragent"; value: "map" }
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.mapping.host"; value: "http://127.0.0.1/osm_tiles/" }
        PluginParameter { name: "osm.mapping.copyright"; value: "All mine" }
    }

    Map {
        id: map

        plugin: mapPlugin
        anchors.fill: parent

        center {
            latitude: -23.5475
            longitude: -46.636110
        }

        zoomLevel: 10
        gesture.enabled: true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out that in order to force the OSM Map plugin to retrieve the tiles from the local server, ones must ensure that the Map's property `activeMapType` is set equal to `MapType.CustomType`. The Qt Location OSM Plugin's documentation is not clear about this. The following code worked for me.

```
Window {
    visible: true

    width: 800
    height: 600

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"

        PluginParameter { name: "osm.mapping.host"; value: "http://127.0.0.1/osm_tiles/" }

    }

    Map {
        id: map

        anchors.fill: parent

        center {
            latitude: -23.5475
            longitude: -46.636110
        }

        zoomLevel: 10

        gesture.enabled: true

        plugin: mapPlugin

        //Make sure to set activeMapType equal to MapType.CustomType
        activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[7]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than presuming that "7" is the magic number to index the custom map type, use the following on the basis that the custom map type is always the last in the list

`activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[supportedMapTypes.length - 1]`